# SharedPreferences File Path Stored unable to load (Flutter Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I am creating a PDF and then I store its local path to Shared Preferences but when I am loading back the file path is printing fine in console but not able to load it as filepath.

Saving

```
var addressp = '$pdffilename$time';
              SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
              sharedPrefs.setString('addressp', addressp);
```

Getting back and store in **address**

```
var  addressp ;
      getValues() async {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs =  await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        setState(() async{
          addressp = sharedPrefs.getString('addressp');
        });

        print('${addressp}');
      }
```

Now when I call it directly its works fine but using variable it do nothing.

```
  PdfViewer (
    // filePath: '/data/user/0/com.myapp/app_flutter/inven1598561218015.pdf',
       filePath: addressp,
                ),
```

Comment: Do not save full path, save relative path, like `/app_flutter/inven1598561218015.pdf`  or `/inven1598561218015.pdf` in your case.

Comment: append your app root path when use it.

Comment: Sir can please give me some sample code as I new to it. Thank you.

Comment: can you provide more detail code then  ?

Comment: https://github.com/divid0n1/inventorycheck/blob/master/lib/ui/myproperty.dart

Answer (score 0):

```dart
// save 
var addressp = '$pdffilename$time';
sharedPrefs.setString('addressp', addressp);


// read
addressp = sharedPrefs.getString('addressp');
PdfViewer (
  filePath: "$documentPath/$addressp",
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Sir Thank you for kind support, I found the actual issue the code PdfViews(filepath: addressp) was being called first which was null and after that the code was getting executed and state was not updating.

Now

I get the first value in previous page and then pass it as variable and its worked fine.